# Why doesn't my JLabel's icon appear?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I am trying to add an icon to my `JLabel`, but the icon does not appear. The icon is an image which is in the same location as my `Frame` class file. Why doesn't the icon appear?

Here is my code:

```
public Passing()
{
    initComponents();

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("altis.jpg");
    jLabel1.setIcon(imageIcon);

    //I have also tried: jLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/res/altis.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get any error?

Comment: nothing error but my label didnt display picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a folder inside your `src` directory called `res`, put the icon inside of `res`, and replace this line:

`ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("altis.jpg");`

with this:

`ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/altis.jpg"));`

(or if that doesn't work):

`ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("res/altis.jpg"));`

Comment: i have an error sir with ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/altis.jpg"));

Comment: methodImageIcon(java.net.url)

Comment: @shampoo Try the code again, I forgot a piece of it. I've edited my answer